# Email notification on Trello about activities when logged out

Tags: trello, notifications

Is there a way to receive email notifications about any activities happening on my Trello Board (cards added, comments posted etc) during my absence (when I am logged out?).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to [subscribe to your board](http://blog.trello.com/board-and-list-subscribe-desktop-notifications-edit-comments-and-more/), which will give you email notifications when the board is changed.

[image: Subscribe to board]